# c# list binding to wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, data-binding

I started to work with WPF's datagrid and faced with the problem.
I have such list

```
private List<ChainCode> _chainCode = new List<ChainCode>();
```

where ChainCode is:

```
public class ChainCode
{
    private uint _number;
    private byte _code;

    public uint Number { get { return _number; } set { _number = value; } }
    public byte Code { get { return _code; } set { _number = value; } }
}
```

So, I want to bind id to such DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridChainCode" ItemsSource="{Binding _chainCode}" CanUserAddRows="True" IsEnabled="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10,35,18,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Number}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="#" Width="60"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Code}" Header="code" Width="60"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

but when I launch my program, I can't add any row to datagrid, cuz there is no row, only headers. And I just have no idea how to fix it.

---

Update:
I made such changes:

```
private ObservableCollection<ChainCode> _chainCode = new ObservableCollection<ChainCode>();
public ObservableCollection<ChainCode> OCChainCode { get { return _chainCode; } set { _chainCode = value; } }
```

and next in xaml:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding OCChainCode}"
```

but there is no response. What I doing wrong?

---

The one thing i understood is than it's too early for me to use WPF. So, I'll try to fix it later

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind to non-public member.
Create property

```
public List<ChainCode> ChainCodeList
{
    get { return _chainCode;}
    set { _chainCode = value;}
}
```

and bind to it.

If your list will change at app lifetime you can use [ObservableCollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: but _chainCode is in <name>.xaml.cs file, in other words, it's declared inside control class

Comment: To get the answer for your question you must understand the binding mechanism behind the scene.

Answer (score 1):

Use ObservableCollection instead of List and implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), if you want the list to update when you change values of Number or Code.

And make your list property public or protected.

Comment: yes and no. you're right about observable collection and INPC, but he still need to change the private var to a property

Comment: Was just fixing that.  :-)

Comment: so, I changed it to: public ObservableCollection<ChainCode> _chainCode = new ObservableCollection<ChainCode>(); bui it's still not working

Comment: If `_chainCode` is not a member of your `DataContext` you need to use a different binding specifier.  Use the name of the window `{Binding ElementName=NameOfWindow, Path=_chainCode}`

Answer (score 0):

In order to use data binding, you need to set the DataContext of the part where you want to use the binding. There are several different ways to set the DataContext, a simple way to do it is in the constructor of the UserControl-class. Usually the DataContext is set to a ViewModel (Using the Model-View-ViewModel-pattern), but it can be any class.

```
public class ViewModel {
   private ObservableCollection<ChainCode> _chainCode = new ObservableCollection<ChainCode>();

   public ObservableCollection<ChainCode> OCChainCode 
   { 
       // No need for a public setter
       get { return _chainCode; }        
   }
}
```

UserControl-class (the class in  [name].xaml.cs file):

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
   public MyUserControl()
   {
      DataContext = new ViewModel();
   }
}
```

You can now use the xaml in your question.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridChainCode" ItemsSource="{Binding _chainCode}" CanUserAddRows="True" IsEnabled="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10,35,18,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Number}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="#" Width="60"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Code}" Header="code" Width="60"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

A thing to note, there are no automatic functionality to add new rows in a DataGrid, you have to write this code yourself. I would suggest a button that creates a new ChainCode-object and adds it to the Observable collection, then it will show up in the UI.